# How to align div in vertical centre of the body?

Tags: html, css

I need to align container in the centre as well as in the middle of the body.
If I add margin-top it adds a white space above the container div and shifts the background image downwards too.
I would prefer everything in percentage.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("../Images/LogIn/Background.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

.Container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
</div>
```

Comment: Did you search for a solution here or online?

Comment: @Rob I did. Can't find anything that'll help with vertical aligning wrt body

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following styles on the bottom to align your child `div` in the center:

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  .container{
    margin:auto;
    width: 50%
  }
```

Any container with a width and relative position when styled with margin auto will automatically center inside a relatively positioned parent div (like body) - if it has content.

```html
<style>
  .container{
    margin:auto;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: grey;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p> text </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Also as a sidenote, you should avoid styling the body at all.

Comment: I needed help with verticall aligning the div.

Comment: grid or flex is the best in that case